# How to send a message containing different data types over mqtt?

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

I am trying to send a message to the broker over a websocket. The message contains numbers that represent sensor data, so the message can be a mix of integers and floats. When I run the code I get `TypeError: payload must be a string, bytearray, int, float or None.` How can the code be changed to send a message containing integers and floats? I am using CloudMQTT as a broker.

Full code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

client = mqtt.Client()
client.username_pw_set("User", "Password")
client.connect("Server", "Port")

num_one = 5.83
num_two = -12.46
num_three = 2

message = (num_one, num_two, num_three)

while True:
    client.publish("topic", message)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that the message you're sending is a tuple. You probably want

```
message = (num_one, num_two, num_three)
message = ''.join([str(x) for x in message])
```

This will convert each number to a string, then join them to a single string.

Comment: This takes all the numbers and joins them into one, but I still want the broker to receive each number.

Comment: replace `''` with `','` and you should end up with a CSV message

Answer (score 0):

Choose an appropriate binary or text based format for your message, and encode your structure in that format. It will then either be a bytearray or string.

Unless there's a good reason to roll your own format, I'd suggest [SenML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8428) as it is barely more complex than most non-standard JSON formats, but is sufficiently standardised you can at least say you're trying to be compatible with other applications.